# Duvida na criação do relacionamento

Tags: doctrine-2

Pessoal eu tenho 2 classes, uma chamada `Venda` e outra `ItensVenda`. Preciso criar um relacionamento para:

1. quando eu abrir uma venda possa ver todos os itens desta venda.
2. quando eu acessar um item de uma venda eu possa ver os dados da Venda.

Como eu crio estes relacionamentos no Doctrine?

Classe `Venda`: `id`, `nome`, `data`

Classe `ItensVenda`: `id`, `nome`, `valor`

Obrigado.

Comment: conseguiu criar o relacionamento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça um relacionamento `OneToMany`.

Classe `Venda`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Venda")
 */
class Venda
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ItensVenda", mappedBy="venda", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    protected $itensVenda;

    /** demais atributos**/
}
```

Classe `ItensVenda`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ItensVenda")
 */
class ItensVenda
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Venda", inversedBy="itensVenda")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="venda_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    protected $venda;

    /** demais atributos**/
}
```

[Fonte](http://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/more-on-one-to-manymany-to-one-associations-in-doctrine-2/)

Comment: opa deu certinho, mas me tire algumas pequenas duvidas. Primeiro o cascade={"remove"} para que serve e tem outros parametros? inversedBy qual a finalidade? Obrigado

Comment: O cascade indica que quando for removido uma venda, os itensVenda serão removidos também. Mais informações na Documentação http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html

Comment: pode marcar como correta a resposta?

Comment: entendi e quanto ao inversedBy para que serve?

Comment: basicamente ele representa o campo no qual ele será presentando pela outra classe, por isso do nome `inversed` . nesse link tem uma ótima documentação sobre relacionamento. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda.